# Chrome faster when performance profiling ON?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a strange situation and I need some ideas.

"Sometimes" I have a performance issue when I am destroying a dom/web component. I am using Google Chrome.
I wanted to see with the profiler what is going on and strangely if I enable the Performance Profiling everything goes well and fast.

I guess it might be an extension I use that is causing the issue, but how can I identify it, without enable/disable all of them?

This screenshot will give you an idea about the response time differences. The second request takes longer (there is more to destroy).

[image]